# Groupby and join working together

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables that I am working with:
MU_Report Table

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | MU
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 68%
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 78%
```

Downtime_Report Table

```
 Date      | Shift | Machine | DT reason|  DT_Hours
 1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | No Work  |    3
 1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Resin |    2
 1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Op.   |    4
 1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    1
 1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    5
```

What I want to do is have the MU_Reports Table look through the Down_Time table in order to get the No Work DT reason from the same day, shift and machine and then sum it.
Output Example

```
 Date      | Shift | Machine | MU   |  No_Work_Hours
 1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%  |     3
 1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 68%  |     0 
 1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 78%  |     6
```

I am using Entity Framework in C# I am very new to both programs so please keep that in mind.

Edit: I converted to a join into but now I have the issue that `downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("R09185")` does not exist in the context

```
       var query = from b in db.MU_Reports
                   join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on b.Shift equals downtime.Shift into o
                   where downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("R09185")
                   select new
                   {
                       Date = b.Date,
                       Shift = b.Shift,
                       Machine = b.Machine,
                       MU = b.MU,
                       No_Work_Hours = o.Sum(x => x.Dt_Hours)
                   };
```

Comment: Why is it 0 for shift 2?

Comment: Have you tried just moving the where statement up one line to before the group?

Comment: @dotctor because the sum for No_Work is 0 for shift 2

Comment: `join` followed by a `group by` smells like `join into` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx

Comment: @TimCopenhaver that fixed one of my issues

Comment: @Dennis_E When I do that then downtime does not exist in the context anymore

Comment: @JCM what is the remaining issue?

Comment: @TimCopenhaver in my where statement the `downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("No_Work")` does not exist in the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
var query = from b in db.MU_Reports
            join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on b.Shift equals downtime.Shift
            where downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("R09185")
            group downtime by new { b.Date, b.Shift, b.Machine, b.MU } into g
            select new
            {
                Date = g.Key.Date,
                Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                Machine = g.Key.Machine,
                MU = g.Key.MU,
                No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(x=>x.Dt_Hours)
            };
```

Comment: group key is now specified.